# Dynamically transposing a table

Tags: sql, db2, zos

I'm trying to figure out how to transpose my result data. It's DB2 Z/OS and we're running version 11.

I'll always have table A specified (As of now about 30 columns, but only three here):

```
Table A
Column_name    Column_id  Data_type  NULL
Product_id         1         N        N
Product_name       2         A        N
Product_status     3         A        Y
```

and then Table B can vary in size.

```
Table B
Product_id  Product_name  Product_status
  101        'First'           NULL
  102        'Second'        'Inactive'
  103        'Third'         'Active'
```

What I want is the following:

```
Result table
Product_number  Column_number   Num_value   Alpha_value   Is_NULL
     101              1            101      
     101              2                       'First'   
     101              3                                    'Y'
     102              1            102      
     102              2                       'Second'  
     102              3                       'Inactive'    
     103              1            103      
     103              2                       'Third'   
     103              3                       'Active'
```

My thinking is that if I could access the columns of Table B by index I should be able to loop through the table and create the result table. I also think it should be possible with a recursive SQL but still need to be able to reference the columns by index.

Any ideas?

Edit:
Table A is supposed to define if the column is Numeric, Alphanumeric and if it can be NULL. It's in reality the easy part as far as I'm concerned, so basically getting the information on the following form is what I want.

```
Product_number  Column_number   Value
     101              1         '101'       
     101              2         'First' 
     101              3         'NULL'     -- Could of course just exclude this line to show that Product_status is NULL for Product_id 101
     102              1         '102'       
     102              2         'Second'    
     102              3         'Inactive'  
     103              1         '103'       
     103              2         'Third' 
     103              3         'Active'
```

Comment: Can be done with a UNION ALL, a select for each type.

Comment: @jarlh You wouldn't mind just giving a rough example?!

Comment: Looking at the result table, it's really not clear how you're trying to combine the data from both tables. I would have thought a straightforward full outer join would be what you'd need to do, but then seeing empty values in 'Is_null' where a 'Y' would be expected, and the mix of values from 'Product_name' and 'Product_status' in 'Alpha_value'. Can you give a more precise description of how you want to combine the data from both tables?

Comment: @FinbarrO'B Hope this clarifies what my main concern is...

Answer (score 0):

This first query represents the table you originally requested:

```
select 
    b.product_id "Product_number",
    a.column_id "Column_number",
    case 
        when a.data_type = 'N' then b.product_id else null 
    end "Num_value",
    case 
        when ( a.data_type = 'A' and a.column_id = 2 ) then b.product_name 
        when ( a.data_type = 'A' and a.column_id = 3 ) then b.product_status else null 
    end "Alpha_value",
    case 
        when a.NULL_ = 'Y' and b.product_Status is null then 'Y' else null 
    end "Is_NULL"
 from  b, a
 order by 1, 2;
```

This second query represents the modified version you posted, however if you are expanding this for additional columns, this will probably be more likely to be buggy for you.

```
 select 
    b.product_id "Product_number",
    a.column_id "Column_number",
    case 
        when a.data_type = 'N' then to_char(b.product_id)
        when ( a.data_type = 'A' and a.column_id = 2 ) then to_char(b.product_name) 
        when ( a.data_type = 'A' and a.column_id = 3 ) then to_char(b.product_status)
        when a.NULL_ = 'Y' and b.product_Status is null then 'Y' 
        else null 
    end "Value"
 from b, a
 order by 1, 2;
```